# R: How do I pass a formula to the linear-model constructor and the resulting linear model to the boxcox method?

Tags: r, transformation, lm

The following script prints a linear-model summary and a Box-Cox plot.

```
library(MASS)
library(monomvn)
formula_string <- "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4"
formula <- as.formula(formula_string)
#linear_model <- lm(formula, data = cement)
linear_model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4, data = cement)
summary_of_linear_model <- summary(linear_model)
print(summary_of_linear_model)
results_of_Box_Cox_Method <- boxcox(linear_model)
```

However, if I switch the commented-in and commented-out definitions of the linear model, the linear-model summary is printed and I received the following error. How do I resolve this?

`Error in x$formula : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be shown to come from the behavior of `model.frame`. It is [described in detail by Bill Dunlap on Rhelp](https://markmail.org/message/4fnn6eubbigmuozd?q=list:org%2Er-project%2Er-help+fmla+environment) in 2016

```
traceback()
15: notnull(x$formula)
14: formula.default(object, env = baseenv())
13: formula(object, env = baseenv())
12: as.formula(formula)
11: model.frame.default(formula = formula, data = cement, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
10: stats::model.frame(formula = formula, data = cement, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
9: eval(mf, parent.frame())
8: eval(mf, parent.frame())
7: lm(formula = formula, data = cement, y = TRUE, qr = TRUE)
6: eval(call, parent.frame())
5: eval(call, parent.frame())
4: update.default(object, y = TRUE, qr = TRUE, ...)
3: update(object, y = TRUE, qr = TRUE, ...)
2: boxcox.lm(linear_model)
1: boxcox(linear_model)
```

...and he shows how to get around it with some environment juggling:

```
formula_string <- "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4"
fmla <- as.formula(formula_string )
#---
localEnvir <- new.env(parent=environment(fmla))
environment(fmla) <- localEnvir
#---
linear_model <- lm(fmla, data = cement)
#
summary_of_linear_model <- summary(linear_model)
print(summary_of_linear_model)
results_of_Box_Cox_Method <- boxcox(linear_model)
# NO error
```